# remove whitespaces from base64 encoded string when posting

Tags: php

I need to remove white spaces from a base64 encoded file. When Base64 gets POSTed, and I get more white spaces in the output string. Where did these white spaces coming

How do I remove these whitespaces?

Comment: what code are you using to generate and post the base64 encoded string?
POSTing a string shouldn't add more whitespace

Comment: Its a image binary string(converted an image to binary and encoded with base64) and posted from iPhone program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Base64 gets POSTed, all pluses(+) are parsed  as spaces. So I used str_replace to convert the spaces back to pluses.
This saved my time

Comment: this is potentially unsafe.
See my answer on why.

Answer (score 2):

If you post a string, depending on how you encoded the POST message, the content of the POST message will be encoded (this might be URLencoded, which is the default in most cases) or HTML encoded.

If your POST message contains a `+` character where there should have been a space, this means it is being URL-Encoded.
If your POST message contains `%20` where there should have been a space, this means it is being HTML-encoded.

PHP offers methods to revert these encoded strings back to the ones they should have been.

`urldecode` (PHP4 and PHP5) [documentation can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

`html_entity_decode` (PHP 4.3.0+ and PHP5) [documentation can be found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: .This is ok when we are communicating php to php ,I think this is a weird state , first time I've been working with PHP and iPhone app ,any way Ben's answer solved my problem ,Sure I will study more about your answer

Comment: url encoding and decoding, as html encoding and decoding should not differ per platform, since they adhere to the same standards.
I have done the same with a MonoTouch iPhone application.