# Received changed PHP post value

Tags: php

I am using the REST API to test web service for mobile application. I have written the web service in PHP & passed the value to "signatureimage" variable as base64 encode string as below

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

but in PHP web service when I print the received the post value it gives the below value

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///
>   l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV
>   wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

Means the "+" character replaced with " "(space). **I want the strictly same passed string as is in PHP web service.**

Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: when printing it try wraping it in `<pre>` tags.. It might be only a display issue

Comment: Same question asked here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032233/remove-whitespaces-from-base64-encoded-string-when-posting

Comment: The string which contacins "+" has posted from mobile application to PHP web service but when I receive it at PHP web service this "+" sign replaced by space. This not regarding only for "+" but I need the sting as is passed from mobile application to PHP web service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace + sign with %2B. There are different ways to do that. like uri_escape(base64_encode($your_base64_string))

Hope it'll resolve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: The string which contacins "+" has posted from mobile application to PHP web service but when I receive it at PHP web service this "+" sign replaced by space. This not regarding only for "+" but I need the sting as is passed from mobile application to PHP web service.