# php generate an image from database but generates a newline first

Tags: php, image, base64

```
header("Content-type: ".$response->strExtension.""); 
header("Content-length: ".$response->intSize.""); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename( $response->strFileName ).""); 
exit(base64_decode($response->binFile));
```

Im generating an image using the above code. But when checking the generated image using notepad++ it has a newline before the data itself so I get error in opening the image. Like below:

[image]

> How can I make sure that the generate file has no space or new lines.

Tried trimming the echoed `base64_decode($response->binFile)` but it didnt do the job. No other echo are executed in this scenario.

Comment: Above code is neither generating the image, nor injecting the newline.

Comment: 1.binFile contains an empty line.   2.save code writes it.

Comment: @shingo binFile is a result of select from database checked it it has no empty line

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of the approaches here for removing whitespaces in your base64: [remove whitespaces from base64 encoded string when posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032233/remove-whitespaces-from-base64-encoded-string-when-posting) . Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. If that link changes, then the answer will be pointless for future visitors. If you find a solution here at StackOverflow, the question should be marked as a duplicate. If you don't have enough rep for that, you should work on that instead.